# Longest sequence of same subsequent number in a square matrix

Tags: java, performance, beginner

Given an N-by-N grid with each cell either occupied by an 'X', an 'O', or empty, write a program to find the longest sequence of consecutive 'X's either horizontal, vertically, or diagonally. To test your program, you can create a random grid where each cell contains an 'X' or 'O' with probability 1/3.

I would like a review of my answer. I'm not sure it's efficient enough, or even efficient at all. I chose to use numbers for now since they easier to work with. I hope it's all clear.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int n = 4;
        int[][] grid = new int[n][n];
        int max =  Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){

                // three nums are produced. there is 1/3 chance for each.
                int r = (int)(Math.random()*3);

                // both 'X' and 'O' have 1/3 chance to be produced. 
                if(r == 1) grid[i][j] = 1;
                if(r == 2) grid[i][j] = 2;

                System.out.print(grid[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        // horizontal, vertical, backward diag, forward diag
        int hori  = 0, vert = 0, bdia = 0, fdia = 0;

        // assuming 1 represents 'X' and 2 represents 'O'
        int num   = (int)(1 + Math.random()*2);

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            hori = 0; vert = 0;
            // horizontal instances  
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                if(grid[i][j] != num)
                    hori = 0;
                else hori ++;
                max = hori > max? hori: max;
            }

            // vertical  instances 
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                if(grid[j][i] != num)
                    vert = 0;
                else vert ++;
                max = vert > max? vert: max;
            }

            // forward diag instances (fdia)
            for(int j = 0; j < n && i == 0; j++){
                if(grid[j][j] != num)
                    fdia = 0;
                else fdia ++;
                max = fdia > max? fdia: max;
            }

            // backward diag instances (bdia) 
            for(int j = 0; j < n && i == 0; j++){
                if(grid[j][n-1-j] != num)
                    bdia = 0;
                else bdia ++;
                max = bdia > max? bdia: max;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("max : "+max);
        System.out.println("num : "+num);
    }
}
```

Comment: In this code: `int num   = (int)(1 + Math.random()*2);`, why are you randomly picking X or O?  I thought the question said to only check for X?

Comment: Um...I should actually had better just said 1. You're right there's no reason to randomly choose between 'O' and 'X'.

Answer (score 2):

Let me start out by saying that your solution certainly is efficient enough. You only loop over the grid once to do the 4 checks. And don't check the same sequence twice. (like going left to right AND right to left).

Since this is codereview.stackexchange let's instead start by reviewing the code :)

---

First of all, there is a mistake in your solution. `Diagonally` is not the same as `on the main diagonals`. The simplest example that you won't find in your solution but what I believe does count as a normal diagonal sequence is the following:

> O X O
>   O O X
>   O O O

This looks like a sequence of lenght 2 to me.

---

I dissagree with you when you say:

> I chose to use numbers for now since they easier to work with.

We can just as well work with `char`:

```
char[][] grid = new char[n][n];
...
if(r == 1) grid[i][j] = 'X';
if(r == 2) grid[i][j] = 'O';
...
if(grid[i][j] == 'X')
```

Doing this also makes it explicit that you're only checking for the X without having to arbitrarily choose if the 'X' is represented by a 1 or a 2 in your grid.

---

You have put all the code inside the `main` method. Although it kinda works for this small problem, it's generally a better idea to split your code up into more manageable blocks.

A few easy ones to separate are a grid generator, and a method to print a grid. By splitting this up into 2 functions we can also provide a fixed grid and still print that grid as well.

Printing is easy. We take the same loops as you already have with the same `System.out...` calls. But without the random setting of the cell.

```
public static void printGrid(char[][] grid){
    for(int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < grid[0].length; col++){
            System.out.print(grid[row][col]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Notice how I named the loop variables `row` and `col` to make it clear what we're looping over.

Randomly generating a grid isn't much harder. We use the same loops, but now we randomly choose one of 3 characters. I'm using `_` to represent "emtpy".

```
public static char[][] generateRandomGrid(int size){
    char[][] grid = new char[size][size];
    for(int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < grid[0].length; col++){
            // three nums are produced. there is 1/3 chance for each.
            int r = (int)(Math.random()*3);

            // both 'X' and 'O' have 1/3 chance to be produced. 
            if(r == 0) {
                grid[row][col] = '_';
            }
            if(r == 1) {
                grid[row][col] = 'X';
            }
            if(r == 2) {
                grid[row][col] = 'O';
            }
        }
    }
    return grid;
}
```

Now for the actual checking of the sequences. This part of your code confused me. You have the outer loop with index `i`. Then depending on what you check the meaning of this `i` changes to the row/the column/something you ignore entirely.

Instead let's provide 4 specific methods, that each calculate the maximum sequence in a specific direction for a given grid.

The horizontal one is easy. It's basically what you already did:

```
public static int findMaxHorizontalSequence(char[][] grid){
    int max = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row < grid.length; row ++) {
        int currentSeq = 0;
        for(int col = 0; col < grid[0].length; col ++){
            if(grid[row][col] == 'X'){
                currentSeq ++;
                if(currentSeq > max){
                    max = currentSeq;
                }
            } else {
                currentSeq = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

The vertical check is almost the same, except the `for` loops are swapped.

```
public static int findMaxVerticalSequence(char[][] grid){
    int max = 0;
    for(int col = 0; col < grid[0].length; col++){
        int currentSeq = 0;
        for(int row = 0; row < grid.length; row ++){
            if(grid[row][col] == 'X'){
                currentSeq ++;
                if(currentSeq > max){
                    max = currentSeq;
                }
            } else {
                currentSeq = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

You might have noticed by now that I always use `grid.length` and `grid[0].length`. This is so that the functions will all work correctly even if the grid was a rectangular shape instead of a square.

For the diagonals we'll have to do a bit more work. The easiest is probably to split it up in 2 loops. One for each of the following lines of starting locations:

```
X X X ?        O O O O  
O O O O        X O O O  
O O O O        X O O O  
O O O O        ? O O O
```

We can ignore the spots with a `?`. Those diagonals are only 1 char long, so it will already be counted by the horizontal/vertical checks. No need to repeat this.

The code could look like this:

```
public static int findMaxDownRightSequence(char[][] grid) {
    int max = 0;
    for (int startRow = 0; startRow < grid.length - 1; startRow++) {
        int currentSeq = 0;
        for (int row = startRow, col = 0; row < grid.length && col < grid[0].length; row++, col++) {
            if (grid[row][col] == 'X') {
                currentSeq++;
                if (currentSeq > max) {
                    max = currentSeq;
                }
            } else {
                currentSeq = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int startCol = 1; startCol < grid[0].length - 1; startCol++) {
        int currentSeq = 0;
        for (int row = 0, col = startCol; row < grid.length && col < grid[0].length; row++, col++) {
            if (grid[row][col] == 'X') {
                currentSeq++;
                if (currentSeq > max) {
                    max = currentSeq;
                }
            } else {
                currentSeq = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

But at this point I really start noticing that I'm copy-pasting a lot. This usually means that we should refactor some common code. The common part of the code that we're copy-pasting is the part inside the inner for loop:

```
if (grid[row][col] == 'X') {
    currentSeq++;
    if (currentSeq > max) {
        max = currentSeq;
    }
} else {
    currentSeq = 0;
}
```

We have to find how to make the for loop work for all cases.
This means: `for(` find initial values for `row` and `col` `;` check if they are still within the bounds of the grid `;` and find how they change each step. `)`

Let's write a method that gets all those parameters and figure out how to map the existing ones to this method. And let's also write a specific method to check if the `row` and `col` are within the bounds of the grid, because otherwise the `for` statement will become unreadable.

```
public static int maxSequence(char[][] grid, int startRow, int startCol, 
                              int verticalDir, int horizontalDir){
    int currentSeq = 0;
    int max = 0;
    for(int row = startRow, col = startCol; 
                checkBounds(grid, row, col); 
                row += verticalDir, col += horizontalDir) {
        if (grid[row][col] == 'X') {
            currentSeq++;
            if (currentSeq > max) {
                max = currentSeq;
            }
        } else {
            currentSeq = 0;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

private static boolean checkBounds(char[][] grid, int row, int col) {
    return row > 0 && col > 0 && row < grid.length && col < grid[0].length;
}
```

Now we can rewrite our other methods. The outer for loops stay the same, but we replace the inner loops with a call to our new method:

```
public static int findMaxHorizontalSequence(char[][] grid) {
    int max = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
        int rowMax = maxSequence(grid, row, 0, 0, 1);
        if(rowMax > max){
            max = rowMax;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

public static int findMaxVerticalSequence(char[][] grid) {
    int max = 0;
    for (int col = 0; col < grid[0].length; col++) {
        int colMax = maxSequence(grid, 0, col, 1, 0);
        if(colMax > max){
            max = colMax;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

public static int findMaxDownRightSequence(char[][] grid) {
    int max = 0;
    for (int startRow = 0; startRow < grid.length - 1; startRow++) {
        int diagMax = maxSequence(grid, startRow, 0, 1, 1);
        if(diagMax > max){
            max = diagMax;
        }
    }
    for (int startCol = 1; startCol < grid[0].length - 1; startCol++) {
        int currentSeq = maxSequence(grid, 0, startCol, 1, 1);
        if (currentSeq > max) {
            max = currentSeq;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

All that's left is to write a method for the other diagonal.

```
    public static int findMaxDownLeftSequence(char[][] grid) {
    int max = 0;
    for (int startRow = 0; startRow < grid.length-1; startRow++) {
        int diagMax = maxSequence(grid, startRow, grid.length, 1, -1);
        if(diagMax > max){
            max = diagMax;
        }
    }
    for (int startCol = 1; startCol < grid[0].length; startCol++) {
        int currentSeq = maxSequence(grid, ?, ?, ?, ?);
        if (currentSeq > max) {
            max = currentSeq;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Since this site requires working code in the first place to review I didn't want to give you the full solution for the diagonals. So try to fill in the four `?` in the last part to see if you fully understood the solution :)

---

To run the new code (and find out if you filled in the last part correctly) you can use the following main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    char[][] grid = new char[][]{{'O', 'X', 'O'},
            {'X', 'O', 'O'},
            {'O', 'O', 'O'}};
    printGrid(grid);
    System.out.println(findMaxSequence(grid));
}
```

or you can replace the grid with

```
char[][] grid = generateRandomGrid(100);
```

To test it out on a random grid.

Fun fact: on my PC it takes between 3.5 and 4 seconds to find the solution of a randomly generated 10000 x 10000 grid. About the same time it takes to randomly generate the grid.

I doubt it can get much faster on a single thread solution. Since you're stuck with looping over the entire grid anyway.